# Sent the Postgresql query result to Log Analytics workspace to create custom metric in Azure Monitor

Tags: azure, azure-log-analytics, azure-monitoring, azure-postgresql

I want to schedule to run a Postgresql query and Azure Monitor will generate a custom metric based on that query result then trigger an email if result return 1. I don't know how to send the SQL query result to Log Analytics workspace that it will create custom metric in Azure Monitor automatically through Kusto Query Language (KQL) as link below

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/alerts/tutorial-log-alert

Comment: Have you tried any query so far? @Hieu Hoang